# Table border not display in dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I tried to generate pdf and store it in the folder.My php code is below:

```
require_once("dompdf-master/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html=$html."<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' /><style>body{font-family:'dejavu sans';font-size:10px;}... </style></head><body>";
.
.
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "landscape");
$dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream("one.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
$canvas->page_text(750, 570, "Page: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
$canvas->page_text(25, 570, "", $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
  $output = $dompdf->output();
  $file_to_save = './uploads/one.pdf';
  file_put_contents($file_to_save,$output );
```

but i got like this: [image]

Here font-family also changed.please anyone help me?

Comment: check your css are conflicting or what.. use `firebug` to verify...

Comment: when i remove the line <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />, i got pdf correctly.But inside the folder it does not saved correctly.it does not encoded.

Comment: You should be calling the `stream()` method last, it ends script execution. Also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29662389/264628